# For loop doesn't increase counter

Tags: java

```
static void nodes(String node) {
  int node_location;
  int i;
  int update_i=1;
  node_location=((node.indexOf("(("))-2);
  ArrayList<String> node_array = new ArrayList<String>();

  for( i=1;i<node_location;i++) {
    if(node.charAt(i)!=',') {
      if(node.charAt(i+1)==',' || node.charAt(i+1)==')')
        node_array.add(Character.toString(node.charAt(i)));
      else {
        for(int a=i+2;a<=node.indexOf("),");a++) {
          update_i++;
          if(node.charAt(a)==',') {
            node_array.add(node.substring(i, a));
            break;
          }
        }
        i=update_i;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This method is supposed to take a string in the format of `(1,2,3,4,5)` and store the numbers (as strings) in an arraylist. The problem is when I have `(1,2,333,4,5)` for example my if statement should go to else and check how many places the digit is before we reach a comma. Then I take the substring of that and store it into my arraylist. The problem is that for some reason the location of I does not update when we get to our else statement (we have to increment more than what the for loop for I does because the digit was more than one place. However when I run it, my program prints out the following:

> 1
>   2
>   333
>   333
>   33
>   3
>   4
>   5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to understand both your code and your question, unfortunately - but this looks relevant:

```
for(int a=i+2;a<=node.indexOf("),");a++)
```

Given that your original string doesn't contain `"),"` at all, `indexOf` will return -1, and you'll never go into your loop body. Therefore `update_i` will never be incremented, and you'll set `i` back to `1`.

I would strongly advise you to completely rewrite your code - at the moment it looks way too complicated for what it's achieving. Can't you split on `,` and then remove any non-digit characters from each string?

Comment: What about the  `node.indexOf("((")` at the start that will always be `-1` as well for his inputs?

Comment: @Esailija Even more, even with the proper index of a (, the -2 would make sure the first loop won't be entered.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the problems is that you only initialize `update_i` at the top, instead of doing it every time you enter the `else` branch.

P.S. Why all the complexity and not just:

```
String[] tok = node.split(",");
```

having removed the parentheses first?

Comment: His variable `update_i` is initialized correctly for its purpose but he made other mistakes in his code that makes it not work as intended. I would also use String's functions instead but that doesn't help him understand his mistakes and what is wrong with his code.

Answer (score 2):

As your question already has been "skeeted", I just have the following remark:

I think you are far better off with regex in this example. Here is code that splits your example string:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "(3,4,555,6,4)";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

output:

> found: 3
>   found: 4
>   found: 555
>   found: 6
>   found: 4

**Explanation:** `\d` (`\\d` in Java to escape the '\') is the shorthand character class for a digit. The `+` means "previous term once or more". The `+` is greedy, so it takes as many of the digits into one match as possible. The rest of the code is just Java syntax for regex matching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `split` method of `String` class as it will be much easier :

```
static void nodes(String node)
{

   ArrayList<String> node_array = new ArrayList<String>();
   String allValues[] = node.split(",");
   for(String value : allValues){
      node_array.add(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not what OP has expected.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani I thought making OP aware of an alternate way

Comment: Thats good, but we have to improve the code what user has applied not the alternate way for the process.

Comment: but I still want to know how to do it my way, thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand and how you want to do it, there's a few mistakes in your code.

Starting with your `node_location` variable that is not initialized correctly, the code you provided makes sure the first loop is not even entered.

Your first loop starts at 1 while indexes of String are 0 based, meaning you're not checking the first character of the `node`. That loop also ends when `i` reaches `node_location`, but, if you want all the numbers between parenthesis in `node`, it should stop when reaching the closing one. So `node_location` should be initialized with the index of `)` in `node`. This is assuming you only have 1 closing parenthesis.

Before your second loop, you should be initializing update_1 with i or you'll update i, after the loop, with 1 + the number of loop done in your else.

Your second loop is not correct either. What you want to do is lopp until you reach a coma or a closing parenthesis. The way you coded the loop for the String you're expecting, as Jon Skeet pointed out, it will return -1 and won't enter the loop.

You should have the same condition to check if you're done with your multiple characters number as you got before `if (node.charAt(i + 1) == ',' || node.charAt(i + 1) == ')') {`. You'll need a variable (either String or StringBuilder) to gather all the characters forming your number so you can add it, once you have them all, to `node_array`. That loop should also ends, if the if is not matched, when it reached `node_location`.

As many mentionned, there's better, simpler solutions to your needs but what I provided here is a good start to improve your own code.