# split method leaving space in array

Tags: java

```
{
    ArrayList<String> node_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    String allValues[] = node.split("[(,)]");

    for(String value : allValues){
        node_array.add(value);
    }
```

node is a string, for example: (3,4,5,6,3)

for some reason when I verify the content of the arraylist the split seems to leave a trail of space as elements, specifically where ( and ) is supposed to be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It leaves an empty string like `""` and not a space `" "`. Thats's how `split()` works. Use what _brimborium_ suggested on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703847/for-loop-doesnt-increase-counter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node.replace("(","").replace(")","").split(",");
```

or

```
node.substring(1,node.length()-1).split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking `split()` to split at parentheses and commas. In your string, there is a blank substring right before the first separator, the opening parenthesis. `split()` is keeping that blank substring and returning it at the zeroth element of the resulting array.

There are plenty of examples in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that illustrate how the function works.

To work around this, you can either ignore the empty strings, or flip the regex on its head and match the numbers instead of splitting at the punctuation characters.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a separator to be the one of the characters that's the first character in your `String`, so an empty string `""` will show up in your `ArrayList`, because that what occurs before the first separator. However, for your application you can easily fix it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> node_array = new ArrayList<String>();
String allValues[] = node.split("[(,)]");

for(String value : allValues){
  if(!value.equals("")) node_array.add(value);
}

return node_array;
```